# MathJax showing normal text in different components of Angular 6

Tags: angular, mathjax, angular6

I am trying to use MathJax in my Angular application. I have got it working in the App Component, however whenever I move the exact code to any other component, it just shows the actual text, not the computed MathJax.

This is the code I used:

```
<div class="mathjax">\(\sqrt b\)</div>
```

I think it might be to do with the `*ngIf` on the `router-outlet`, which I use to wait until the data from firebase has loaded.

```
<router-outlet *ngIf="this.coursesService.is_loading == false"></router-outlet>
```

Does the `*ngIf` stop the MathJax from loading properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the `*ngIf`. No matter what I did, I couldn't get MathJax to work. In the end, the solution was very simple: I used the `ng-katex` module instead, at https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-katex.
This works with the routing and the `*ngIf` without problem.